# Make Selected part of text Bold/Unbold with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, text

When writing something in “input” it’s real-time visible in div. It’s necessary that when B button is pressed the selected text in div turns bold and then it becomes unbold when pressed again. But I don't need any library or framework. I need to use only JavaScript. I tried getSelection methods and execCommand but they did not help․

```js
const textArea = document.getElementById("textArea");
const input = document.getElementById("input");
const bold = document.getElementById("bold");

let span = document.createElement("span");

input.addEventListener("input", e => {
  span.textContent = e.target.value;
  textArea.appendChild(span);
});
```

```css
#textArea {
  width: 360px;
  height: 350px;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 15pt;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  overflow: scroll;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
}

button {
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.inputDiv {
  margin-top: 5px;
}

#input {
  width: 370px;
  height: 50px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  background-color: #ccc;
  font-size: 15pt;
}

#workspace button {
  width: 50px;
  margin: 5px auto;
  background-color: #d9d9d9;
}

#workspace button:hover {
  width: 50px;
  margin: 5px auto;
  background-color: #999999;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="myDiv">
    <div id="workspace">
      <button id="bold">B</button>
      <div id="textArea"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="inputDiv">
      <input type="text" name="text" id="input" placeholder="type something...">
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Add a css class with your style, and toggle it with Javascript. el.toggle('class-name')

Comment: Thank you, but I need to change style of selected part of text, not all

Comment: put that part in an element like span and select that element.

Comment: If I select part of text and make that bold using span with style, I can’t make it back to unbold or select other part of text, because I need to add spans for every selection

Comment: Toggle actually removes the class or adds it if it does not exist whenever it is triggered so it removes the bold style if it has that class. And for selecting the whole text even in span you can use el.textContent or innerText on the parent of span based on your need.

Comment: Please show me an example if you can.

Comment: For example if my text is “Hello World!” and I select only “World” and change it to bold after that I select only “rld” and want to make it unbold, it doesn’t work.

Comment: Do you want to set the bold style in textarea? if yes, that's not a good approach. You can use contenteditable on another element like p. It's an HTML property. And if you don't want to edit it, just use another element. And I don't understand where do want to select the "rdl" for example and how? Do you want to correct typing errors, for example?

Comment: Could you show us how you tried to use getSelection because I cannot understand how this can possibly work without using it. Also, is the text to remain bold even when a different selection is made? (as if in an editor for example). This isn't clear from your code because you only create one span element.

Comment: state = {
    isBoldActive : false
}
let a = (style) => {
    var span = document.createElement("span");
    span.style.fontWeight = style;
    if (window.getSelection) {
        var sel = window.getSelection();
        if (sel.rangeCount) {
            var range = sel.getRangeAt(0).cloneRange();
            range.surroundContents(span);
            sel.removeRange(range);
            sel.addRange(range);
        }
    }
}

Comment: const changeFont = style => () => {
    if (style === "bold"){
        if(state.isBoldActive === false){
            bold.style.backgroundColor = "#404040";
            a(style);
        } else {
            bold.style.backgroundColor = "#d9d9d9";
            a(style);
        }  
        state.isBoldActive =  !state.isBoldActive;
    } 
} 
bold.addEventListener("click", changeFont("bold"));

Comment: This is my code, it's make selected part of text bold, but can't unbold it

Comment: Your problem is the passing style to the "a" function. You have to change it back to normal. Check this [link](https://jsbin.com/zabadid/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: And what can I do?

Comment: `const changeFont =  () => { 
  if(state.isBoldActive === false){ 
    bold.style.backgroundColor = "#404040";
    a("bold"); 
  state.isBoldActive = !state.isBoldActive; 
  } 
    else { 
      bold.style.backgroundColor = "#d9d9d9"; 
      a("normal"); 
    state.isBoldActive = !state.isBoldActive; 
  } 
}
bold.addEventListener("click", changeFont);`

Comment: Sorry, but it doesn't change anything, I can't unbold selection part?